# Between clause not giving desired results in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to return results from a mssql stored proc on the basis of datetime2. There's a employee table with punch in and punch out time. I need to return results all the data from an employee on the basis of start time and end time. My query is some what like

```
Select * 
from   employee 
where  empid ='123' 
and     punchin  between 'starttime' and 'endtime' 
and     punchout between 'starttime' and 'endtime'
```

this query is not returning expected results. Am I doing anything wrong here, also in between punch in or punch out column one can be empty, in that case result will be returned on the basis of one column.

Comment: Where is your exact query? And show sample data and your desired data from that sample data.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some table schema, sample data, an actual query and expected results? You say it's not returning expected results, so it's really important you tell us what you expect the results to be.

Comment: `'starttime'` and `'endtime'` are literal string containing words; this never work against a date and time data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on assumption:

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  empid VARCHAR(20) not null,
  punchin datetime2(7),
  punchout datetime2(7)
)
```

**Sample data:**

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES
('1', null, '2021-03-28 10:50:00'),
('2', '2021-03-28 05:00:00', '2021-03-28 9:00:00'),
('3', '2021-02-28 05:00:00', null)
```

**Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getData
@empid VARCHAR(20),
@startTime datetime2(7),
@endTime datetime2(7)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM employee
  WHERE empid = @empid
    AND (punchin IS NULL OR (punchin IS NOT NULL AND punchin >= @startTime))
    AND (punchout IS NULL OR (punchout IS NOT NULL AND punchout <= @endTime))
END
```

**Usage:**

```
EXEC getData '1', '2021-03-27 10:50:00', '2021-03-27 10:50:00'
```

See, if it works.

**Note:** Without proper structure or data, it is hard to do things based on assumption.

Comment: I recommend you remove the prefix for the object here though @RThinker . The `sp_` is reserved by Microsoft and should ***not*** be used for user objects.